# SVG file as favicon

Tags: templates, icon

I want to insert an svg file as favicon in Joomla. I have found the function **addFavicon** in Joomla core files (/libraries/joomla/document/html/html.php) which inserts the favicon link but I don't know how to use it and where in my template.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried using an SVG as a favicon, but the `addFavicon` function is part of the `JDocumentHTML` class, therefore you should use it like so:

```
$path = JUri::root() . 'templates/MY_TEMPLATE/file.svg';
$type = 'image/svg+xml';
$rel  = 'icon';

$doc = JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->addFavicon($path, $type, $rel);
```

Comment: Inserting the addFavicon function in the UpdateHead() function of my template did the trick. The page source now shows the html code for changing the favicon.